# Yup Nested Object Enum Validation

Tags: schema, yup, react-hook-form

I have this data transfer object that I am using with react hook form and typescript, the ExampleDto object has nested objects and enums.

```
export interface ExampleDto {
    name: string;
    uid: string;
    use: UseEnum;
    teamRoles: TeamRoles;
    isActive: boolean;
}
```

The following is a nested enum

```
export enum UseEnum {
    Sport = "Sport",
    Casual = "Casual",
}
```

and the following is a nested object whose properties all have the same enum

```
export interface TeamRoles {
    Advisor?: TeamRoleEnum[];
    Sales?: TeamRoleEnum[];
    Marketing?: TeamRoleEnum[];
    Accounting?: TeamRoleEnum[];
    Finance?: TeamRoleEnum[];
    HumanResources?: TeamRoleEnum[];
}

export enum TeamRoleEnum {
    Advisor = "Advisor",
    Sales = "Sales",
    Marketing = "Marketing",
    Accounting = "Accounting",
    Finance = "Finance",
    HumanResources = "HumanResources",
}
```

this is the schema I am trying to build

```
const schema: yup.ObjectSchema<ExampleDto> = yup
    .object({
        name: yup.string().max(100).required('Required'),
        uid: yup.string().max(100).required('Required'),
        use: yup.mixed<UseEnum>().oneOf(Object.values(UseEnum)).required('Required'),
        teamRoles: yup.mixed<TeamRoles>()
            .object({
                SeniorConsultant: yup.mixed<TeamRoleEnum>().oneOf(Object.values(TeamRoleEnum)),
                Consultant: yup.mixed<TeamRoleEnum>().oneOf(Object.values(TeamRoleEnum)),
                SeniorRegistrar: yup.mixed<TeamRoleEnum>().oneOf(Object.values(TeamRoleEnum)),
                Registrar: yup.mixed<TeamRoleEnum>().oneOf(Object.values(TeamRoleEnum)),
                Resident: yup.mixed<TeamRoleEnum>().oneOf(Object.values(TeamRoleEnum)),
                Intern: yup.mixed<TeamRoleEnum>().oneOf(Object.values(TeamRoleEnum)),
            })
            .required('Required'),
        isActive: yup.boolean().required('Required'),
    })
    .defined();
```

The schema is not correct, it gives me the error Property 'object' does not exist on type 'MixedSchema '.

I am struggling to find examples of this level of complexity